# I am a new learner of Python, and I am having a major problem with my code

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, math

The problem can be summarized below in this snippet of code.

```
#! python3

people = {
    "alice": {
        "style": "bun",
        "length": 5},
    "bob":{
        "style": "ponytail",
        "length": 19}
}
cut = people["alice"["length"]] =+ 1
print("Alice's hair length is" + str(cut))
```

I tried adding and taking away the quotation marks around "alice" and "length" and using the .get() function, among other things, trying to get it to read (in this example) "Alice's hair length is 20". Instead I got a variety of syntax errors and "TypeError: String indices must be integers", depending on what I tried. This seems like a simple issue where I am missing something glaringly obvious. Thank you for your time and assistance!

Comment: I get no syntax errors. As a learner you should do these lookups in pieces until you get the hang of it. First do something like `alice_info = people["alice"]` and then something like `alice_info["length"] += 1 `. Then you may realize that you can combine them into `people["alice"]["length"] += 1`.

Comment: Did you intend to increase the length by one and then assign that to `cut`?

Comment: The part `"alice"["length"]` causes `"TypeError: String indices must be integers"`. I think you want to use something like
`people["alice"]["length"]`. But I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve. If it's just printing a hair length without changing any data in `people`, try `print("Alice's hair length is " + str(people["alice"]["length"] ))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are very close! `people["alice"]` would return the inner dictionary ready for your next index. Its a bit subtle, but `=+ 1` assigns `+1` to the length and also the cut. So you need to do something there. I changed the code to assign `cut` to the length plus one. That's a guess on what you wanted.

```
cut = people["alice"]["length"] + 1
```

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk - right. I hit "save" a bit too eary.